# I want to display everything that appears in the debug console, for the user when the app is in production

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like to show the user the messages that appear for us developers, to be more specific I would like to show the user what appears to us in the terminal in the debugConsole tab, I would like to show the user the messages that appear there.
example this information from the debug console in real time for the user

[image]

i try some packages but none got successed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible for all kinds of logs that are triggered from different platforms inside a flutter app when it's released, there are many reasons such as when the `log()` from the `dart:developer` shows a statement in the console log only in the debug mode, not the release mode.

However, you can make it happen for your project's `print()`, `debugPrint()` by combining these methods with a `StreamController`, `Stream` like this :

**1. First we create a `StreamController`:**

```
StreamController streamController = StreamController<String>();
```

**2. make new methods for `print`, `debugPrint` methods that notify that `streamController` every time:**

```
   void customPrint(Object? object) {
     streamController.add(object.toString());
     print(object);
    }
```

**3. listening to the `Stream` of `StreamController` to show the messages in the app, as an example :**

```
   StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        stream: streamController.stream, // the stream of the controller
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }
      ),
```

now you can change all your `print()` calls with the `customPrint()`, and every time it's called, it will be printed in the console log, and also be shown in the UI of the Flutter app.